# IOS Capture 12 MP Video (IPhone 6s) yields 1000x750

Tags: ios, iphone, avcapturesession, avcapture, avcaptureoutput

According to https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/21694

> Both iPhone 6s and 6s Plus can capture 12 megapixel photos (4032x3024)
>   on the rear-facing camera via the AVCaptureStillImageOutput, and can
>   deliver up to 30 fps 12 MP frames to your process via
>   AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.  When you use AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto as
>   your AVCaptureSession’s -sessionPreset, the 12 megapixel ‘420f’ format
>   is chosen by default.

So I tried to do so with the following code:

```
self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput*   videoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
videoOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES;
[videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch];
[self.captureSession addOutput:videoOutput];
```

My device's active format is set to:

> device format: AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x12c684630 'vide'/'420f'
>   4032x3024, { 3- 30 fps}, fov:57.716, max zoom:189.00 (upscales @1.00),
>   AF System:2, ISO:23.0-1840.0, SS:0.000013-0.333333

which looks good.

However, I added the following code to the `captureOutput` callback:

```
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBufferRef,0);
size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBufferRef);
size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBufferRef);
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBufferRef,0);
NSLog(@"ImageCameraSource:\n   width:%zu\n   height:%zu\n", width, height);
```

And it outputs

> ImageCameraSource:
>   width:1000 
>   height:750

Why isn't the resolution in the callback 4032x3024?

Comment: I feel your pain man...

Comment: I've been investigating this.  Are you trying to obtain 4032x3024 frames from `captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!)` or `stillImageCaptureOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection)`?

Comment: from the captureOutput. Why? Is this wrong?

Comment: What I found in my app is when using AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto, `didOutputSampleBuffer` buffers are 1000x750, but a buffer returned from `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` outputs 3264x2448.  I found this out by looking at the highResolutionImageDimensions on the session's default AVCaptureDeviceFormat: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDeviceFormat_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureDeviceFormat/highResolutionStillImageDimensions

Comment: If I had to take a guess, I'd say the API returns 1000x750 buffers 30/sec in the Photo preset to use for video preview, and expect people will grab still frames when they need them with `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection`

Comment: sounds like a good guess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `AVCaptureSessionPreset3840x2160` to get highest res frames in real time

```
self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset3840x2160;
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput*   videoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
videoOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES;
[videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch];
[self.captureSession addOutput:videoOutput];
```